# Inheritance : error: aggregate typeA has incomplete type and cannot be defined

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am trying to create a derived class object in base class method.

I am getting the error as mentioned above. Below is a code snippet.

Any help?

```
 ---- Voip_connection.hh ---- 

   #ifndef __VOIP_CONNECTION_HH
   #define __VOIP_CONNECTION_HH

 class VoipConnection {
 public:

VoipConnection();
VoipConnection (ConnectionState* cs);

void update_last_data_rcvd_time() { last_data_rcvd_time_ = msec_time(); }
uint64_t last_data_rcvd_time() { return last_data_rcvd_time_; }
void set_voip_proto(int proto) { voip_proto_ = proto;}

~VoipConnection()
{
    --nx_stat().act_connections;
    voip_idle_wait_timer_clear();
    sv_streaming_offset_ = 0;
    cl_streaming_offset_ = 0;
}


// Lots and Lots of Other stuff



  }


----Voip_sip.hh -----

#ifndef __VOIP_SIP_HH
#define __VOIP_SIP_HH
#include "voip_connection.hh"

class SipObj: public VoipConnection 
{

    /* stuff */
} 


--- Voip_connection.cc ----
#include "voip_connection.hh"

class SipObj; // Tried this in .hh file as well. 

VoipConnection::voip_process_pdu(bool from_client) 
{
 SipObj sip;
 sip.process(datap, &pdu_len);
 }
```

Comment: Perhaps `VoipConnection` has no public default constructur? You need to provide its source code. If you don't define any constructor in `SipObj`, the compiler doesn't know how to initialize the underlying `VoipConnection`.

Comment: it seems VoipConnection has a non-default constructor which you need to address with the SipObj constructor

Comment: If a base class is trying to instantiate a derived class, that's probably a sign that your inheritance hierarchy is upside-down.

Comment: This question is ambiguous, there is one error in the title and another in the actual question. Please choose a better title and put both errors in the question. Or even better, ask one question with one error, and when that's solved and you still have errors, then ask another question.

Comment: You have to show more of the `VoipConnection` class, especially your constructors. Preferably you should show the whole class declaration.

Comment: I have shown some parts of it

Comment: After your edit `SipObj` contains constructors and destructor of `VoipConnection`. There must be something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to instantiate a class, you need the complete type. This

```
SipObj sip;
```

requires the full definition of `SipObj`. A simple forward declaration won't do, you need to include the appropriate header.

In general, I would say that having a base class depend explicitly on one of it's derived types is a pretty bad idea.

Concerning the other error you report, it simply says that class `VoipConnection` has no default constructor. So you will have to provide one.

Comment: What you mention will lead to another error, but it's not the error that this question is about.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the error on the question's title is the one I am dealing with here.

Comment: Okay, I only checked the error in the question, not in the title.

Answer (score 1):

The second error points out that class `VoipConnection` has no default constructor which the constructor of `SipObj` tries to call.

The forward declaration of `SipObj` in `Voip_connection.cc` looks strange. Why does the implementation of a base class needs to know the existence of a derived class?

Comment: Regarding using the derived class in the base class, it's maybe not usual but it's common enough that it's got a named pattern: [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Comment: VoipConnection object is created during connection set up and based on the packet, VoipConnection decides which object it belongs to,.. like SipObj, XAZObj..etc.. So rightfully it has to create the object of its child and hand over the packet so that it can do the processing.

Comment: OK, this looks like you need a different architecture. Something like a `SetupConnection` class which then constructs the appropriate connection class derived from a common interface and passes the relevant data for construction.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this what I did. I needed the base class to instantiate the derived class..
I did the forward declaration in voip_sip.hh and included the voip_sip.hh file in voip_connection.hh

```
---- Voip_connection.hh ---- 

 #ifndef __VOIP_CONNECTION_HH
 #define __VOIP_CONNECTION_HH
 #include voip_sip.hh

class VoipConnection {

// Lots and Lots of Other stuff

}

----Voip_sip.hh -----

#ifndef __VOIP_SIP_HH
#define __VOIP_SIP_HH
class VoipConnection;

class SipObj: public VoipConnection 
{

/* stuff */
} 


--- Voip_connection.cc ----
#include "voip_connection.hh"
#include "voip_sip.hh"


VoipConnection::voip_process_pdu(bool from_client) 
{
 SipObj sip;
 sip.process(datap, &pdu_len);
 }
```

Comment: It sounds similar to what I suggested you do.